# $scope not updating when set from $http promise context

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to chain several `$http` calls, and then display the response of the last `$http` call. The calls all work correctly and the proper response is displayed, but only for the very first time I run the chain of calls. On subsequent runs, it makes it through the `$http` calls, but does not update the view with the latest response.

I can see in both Firefox and Chrome console network logs, that all the calls within the chain are getting executed (even on subsequent runs of the chain). In debugging the issue, I've replaced the `$http` calls with simple data assignment and everything works - including updates to the view - so at this point I'm mostly confident it's related to the `$http/promise`. Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong, or pointers on where to look as I start to read up on Angular.

Thanks.

I'm on Angular version 1.2.16. and here's my code:

```
//controller
function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost:8080/call/one')
    .then(function(responseOne) { return responseOne.data })
    .then(function(dataFromCallOne) {
      return $http.jsonp('http://localhost:8080/call/two')
        .then(function(responseTwo) { 
          $scope.results = responseTwo.data
        });
    });
}
```

In my view, I have

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{results}}
  <button ng-click="makeCall()">Call</button>
</div>
```

I've tried, the following but still no updates to my view, both methods work for initial display of results, but not on subsequent updates:

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
 $scope.$apply()
}
```

and assigning chain results to $scope.result

```
$scope.results = $http.get('http://localhost:8080/call/one')
    .then(function(responseOne) { return responseOne.data })
    .then(function(dataFromCallOne) {
      return $http.jsonp('http://localhost:8080/call/two')
        .then(function(responseTwo) { return responseTwo.data });
    });

$scope.results.then(function(data) { 
  $scope.results = data 
});
```

Comment: Try $scope.apply(function(){$scope.results = responseTwo.data;});

Comment: I've tried $apply, but it's not working for me - thanks though.

Comment: In principle your code should work, *but there is no `json()` method* in `$http`! Angular has a `$http.jsonp()` method. This is according to [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/service/$http). Are missing a console error?

Comment: I meant jsonp - typo. I'm not getting any console errors, data is retrieved from $http calls (I can see in network logs), just not updated to view on subsequent updates.

Comment: What do you mean with subsequent updates? When and how is the function called?

Comment: function is called from an ng-click on a button. First time I call the function (e.g. click button), everything works - both $http calls in the chain complete, and then $scope.results is updated and shows up on view. When I click button again, the $http calls complete (response data in logs is different) but the $scope.results is not updated in the view to reflect what's been returns in the $http responses.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. In my chain of `$http` calls, one of them is an `$http.jsonp()` call. When using JSONP, Angular requires a `callback` param - specifically called `JSON_CALLBACK`. This JSON_CALLBACK, then gets replace by an internally generated, unique callback name, right before the request is made.

```
 ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK --> ?callback=angular.callbacks._0
 ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK --> ?callback=angular.callbacks._1
 ?callback=JSON_CALLBACK --> ?callback=angular.callbacks._2
```

This was problematic for me since my `jsonp` request is to an OAuth provider that required signing the complete url (including the callback param). So initially I would sign the url with `callback=JSON_CALLBACK`, but Angular would turn it to something like `callback=angular.callbacks._#`. I would get an OAuth error since the signature and actual url didn't jive. Anyways, at some point I hard coded `callback=angular.callbacks._0`, just so I could get my OAuth client code working, but I forgot all about it.

Now subsequent calls to `$http.jsonp()` with non-unique callback params were not being processed after the response was returned. That's why my $scope is not updated after $http promise.

My hack at the moment is to continue using the hard coded callback=angular.callbacks._#, but with incrementing numbers.